# Brand name showing before the title in search results

Tags: seo, wordpress, google-search, title

If we search for our brand name or any keywords that relate to our website, the first words to appear in the title shown in the Google result preview follow this format:

`Brand Name: Title`

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I am using Yoast WordPress SEO, and each of the pages are not optimized the same as the above result.

Here's the WordPress code:

```
<title><?php wp_title('&laquo;', true, 'right'); ?> <?php  bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
```

If we comment out the PHP code inside the title, the page itself has no title then.

I wanted to have the title first, followed by the brand name in the search results.

Comment: Yep, see my answer below :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the Title Template for your site's `<title>` tag, as covered [here](http://yoast.com/articles/wordpress-seo/#titles).

In the SEO section of your Admin, navigate to: *SEO → Titles & Metas*

Make sure you have the `title` variable followed by the `sitename` variable, as pictured below. To see what each variable is for, see the bottom of the settings page:

[image]

Comment: I have this format: `%%title%% %%page%% %%sep%% %%sitename%%`, should I just copy the your example above?

Comment: Taking a look at your source code now...

Comment: It looks your source code has this for a meta title: `Hotel Management System | Custom Software | Reservation and Queue | Jinisys Software Inc`. It seems Google can't use that, so placed your company name first, followed by part of your title. So I would try the example in the screenshot, as that would shorten it to just the `title` and `sitename`, which Google may be able to then use. That should result in something like:  `Hotel Management System | Jinisys Software Inc`.

Comment: Thanks, The meta title is purposely done by us. I have replaced my prev format with yours. I am not sure what you  meant by shorten it up, we need the meta title as it is. Does it mean that the title will be truncated or the company name will be removed and placed at the last?

Comment: No problem. See my comment above, it should look like that after modified (with the other variable information removed). Google tries to use whatever title it finds in your source code (view the source code for that page). If it can't use your title (e.g., because it's too long), then it will create another one for that page.

Comment: Just to confirm my understanding, the `|` separator and the too long title triggers Google to re-arrange the title but I need the long title for keyword targeting. What should I do? *sobs.. .should I just make it as one sentence form?

Comment: I can't speak as to what will work best for Google, just that it chose to generate one for that page based on what it found - see the second to the last paragraph [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?rd=1#3). So my suggestion would be to shorten it to just the variables that contain keywords relevant to the content of that page. One last suggestion is to use the HTML Improvements tool found [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80407).

Comment: I learned a lot for today! Thank you @dan. Enjoy the rest of your day and have a good one!!!!!

Comment: :-) You too. Take a look at the last two links in my comments, they should be helpful to you in the future.