# Display only the Post title by avoiding site name?

Tags: wordpress, search-engines, search-engine-indexing

I am using wordpress. How i can remove the site name from search result. I want to show just the title of my post. Below is an example.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing a plug-in such as Yoast for SEO, and change the template for SEO Title in the settings.

Comment: I have already tried this when i first created the website. It may work for some post, but not every.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress you have two options for removing the site name from your page titles.

1. Edit the code for the `wp_render_title_tag` (you can add a filter to your theme to do so).
2. Change the `<title>` tag in your theme to `<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>`

See [How can I remove the sitename or homepage title from all page titles?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/223325/how-can-i-remove-the-sitename-or-homepage-title-from-all-page-titles) on wordpress.stackexchange.com

---

Even if you don't put the site name into your `<title>` tags, Google will usually rewrite your title in the search results to add your site name.   There is no way to tell Google not to do this.  Google does so because:

- Google wants to help you build your brand
- Having site names improves click through rate
- It is good for user experience

Google covers this in their help document: [Create good titles and snippets in Search Results - Search Console Help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en)

> Brand your titles, but concisely. The title of your site’s home page is a reasonable place to include some additional information about your site—for instance, "ExampleSocialSite, a place for people to meet and mingle." But displaying that text in the title of every single page on your site hurts readability and will look particularly repetitive if several pages from your site are returned for the same query. In this case, consider including just your site name at the beginning or end of each page title, separated from the rest of the title with a delimiter such as a hyphen, colon, or pipe, like this: `<title>ExampleSocialSite: Sign up for a new account.</title>`
>
> ...
>
> If we’ve detected that a particular result has one of the above issues with its title, we may try to generate an improved title from anchors, on-page text, or other sources.

Google has been doing this since at least 2011.  People have been noticing it or complaining about it since: [1](https://moz.com/community/q/google-automatically-adding-company-name-to-serp-titles), [2](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/120802/wrong-website-title-shows-up-in-google-serp), [3](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14415/title-tag-different-from-title-appearing-in-google), [4](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67971/force-google-not-to-include-my-sites-name-in-my-pages-title), [5](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102956/why-is-my-domain-name-getting-appended-to-the-title-in-google-serp), [6](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57046/brand-name-showing-before-the-title-in-search-results)

Comment: Your answer may be wrong. Please look at the added image.

Comment: WhatsApp is the brand in the first and "app store" is the name of that Apple subdomain.  If Apple had named that page just "WhatsApp", Google would have added to their title for them.

Comment: It is possible. Please refer the changed image.

Comment: Google occasionally chooses not to rewrite titles.  That doesn't mean that you can force them not to add your brand to your titles.   The best that you can do is remove you site name from your titles and hope that Google doesn't put it back all the time.   I edited the answer to give you the WordPress instructions you are looking for.